Tailwind opacified color doesn't render the same on the background and the border
Using the Tailwind color purple-600/50 on both the background and the border of an element, they don't render the same color. It's like the opacity is not the same (tested on Firefox and Safari). See https://play.tailwindcss.com/KrjtSAezXQ.
<img src="/img/logo.svg" class="h-6 bg-purple-600/50 border-purple-600/50 border-4 rounded-full" />


However, inspecting the css shows the same rules :

background-color: rgba(147, 51, 234, 0.5);
border-color: rgba(147, 51, 234, 0.5);


The image being used doesn't seem to have an intrinsic background opacity, or the same would happen with no css opacity :

<img src="/img/logo.svg" class="h-6 bg-purple-600 border-purple-600 border-4 rounded-full" />

What am I missing ?

I do not know why such things happen, but on chrome I tried this: <img src="/img/logo.svg" class="h-6 bg-purple-600/50 border-purple-600/5 border-4 rounded-full" alt="Tailwind Play" />
Curiously, why need a border when the border share the same color as the background?

The border needs a lesser opacity than the background

@M.Riyan Good catch ! but there is actually a slight difference. It looks as expected with border-purple-600/0, which normally should render has completely transparent. There seems to be some sort of "inverse cumulative opacity" then …

By default, the border gets drawn on top of the the background. Thus, the border color gets overlaid on to the background color, hence the difference in color.
If you want the same color in both situations you could consider:

Using background-clip: padding-box via the bg-clip-padding class to stop the background color being drawn underneath the border:



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<img src="https://play.tailwindcss.com/img/logo.svg" class="h-6 bg-purple-600/50 border-purple-600/50 border-4 rounded-full bg-clip-padding" />




Emulating the border with padding around the image:



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<img src="https://play.tailwindcss.com/img/logo.svg" class="h-6 bg-purple-600/50 p-[4px] rounded-full" />



